# Rails: How to filter results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In the index action of my Users controller, I am able to capture all users belonging to the same city as the `current_user` in an ActiveRecord::Relation object `@users`. In my view I am able to iterate through `@users` and display the results. What I'd like to do is give the `current_user` further options to filter the results. I want to add a form and filter button in the view, which will allow the current_user to select filters, such as:

1. Minimum Age and Maximum Age (Drop Down)
2. Religion (Drop down of checkboxes)
3. Diet (Drop down of checkboxes)
4. And so on.

Once the current_user makes the selections and clicks on filter, the results will be filtered based on the criteria selected. I want to know how to build a query to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's also relatively simple to do this yourself without a library by creating scope methods in your user model.  For example:

```
 class User

   def self.filtered_by_age(opts = {})
     min = opts[:min]
     max = opts[:max]
     user = User.arel_table

     if min && max
       self.where(:age => min..max)
     elsif min && !max
       self.where(user[:age].gt(min))
     elsif max && !min
       self.where(user[:age].lt(max))
     else
       self.all
     end
   end

 end
```

Which you could then call with

```
@users.filtered_by_age(min: 25, max: 52)
```

Comment: Can I chain the scopes? Mening can I do something like `@users.filtered_by_age(min: 25, max: 52)`, `@users.filtered_by_education("Bachelors")` and so on. Or would I need to combine all of them in 1 query?

Comment: you can do both, either by overwriting the instance variable each time like this: `@users = @users.filtered_by_age(min:25), @users = @users.filtered_by_education(..), @users = @users.filtered_by...etc` or by chaining the query like `@users.filtered_by_age(min:25).filtered_by_education("bachelor").filtered_by....etc.`

Comment: You may want to handle `nil` cases in either or both of `opts`. Or perhaps even better - declare `self.filtered_by_age(min, max)`

Comment: I see the `nil` cases are actually handled, however shoulnd't you return `self.all` too

Answer (score 4):

Best bet would either be Ranksack: https://github.com/ernie/ransack
This provides search focused functionality.

OR

Squeel provides an easy to use interface for advanced querying for ActiveRecord: https://github.com/ernie/squeel