# Building a selectbox or filter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hi maybe this is a fool question, but i really try to look couldnt find any relevant info, (maybe cause i dont know where exactly to start looking at) ..

I need to build a select box with options so the user can "filter" by the candidate.poisition value i have. at this moment the view has this code..

I was thingin on using :params, to post them in URL (i have always do php, im doing rails cause my task now is to insert a design, i achieve everything, just missing a selectbox filter)

Anyway.. here is the code.. wich is pretty simple

```
    <% @candidates.each do |candidate| %>

      <% if (candidate.active == true) && (candidate.position.present?) %>

All the html code with info.. like 

<%= candidate.name %> : <%= candidate.position? ? t('generales.'+candidate.position) : t('activerecord.models.elite') %>

    <% end %>

    <% end %>
```

how can i make this , as im really a noob in Rails, im a regular user on PHP not even really good jaja, pls, i hope someone can give me a hand on this.

Can I use something like this : [How to do a LIKE query in Arel and Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430578/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-arel-and-rails-3)

Like `candidates.where("position like '%?%'", params[:query]).to_sql`

Also how can i build the Post as you do in PHP , no idea, to change the position that you want to filter.

Model Candidate.rb just have this inside :S

```
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: Doing a select that filters a list involves a certain number of steps. For instance: the select itself, the controller action, the JavaScript part if you're doing this with AJAX. It's not clear which of these your question is about. Also, it's not clear how the code snippet you posted relates to the question.

Comment: I always work in PHP , i also know AJAX but i have no idea of how to implement it on rails..  in PHP yo post a $var that will sent the information to modify query, or condition query. but here, i have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're right. Here is improved code:

```
<% @candidates.each do |candidate| %>
  <% if candidate.active && candidate.position.present? %>

    <%= candidate.name %> : <%= t("generales.#{candidate.position}") %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Update per request in comments:**

Use code like this in controller:

```
if params[:position] == 'red'
  @candidates = @candidates.where(position: 'red') 
elsif params[:position] == 'blue'
  @candidates = @candidates.where(position: 'blue') 
else
  @candidates = Candidate.all
end
```

and build html form that will pass parameter `position`.

or you can use https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Comment: but that code its already working fine.. i just need to make a select box to filter by candidate position.. im a rails noob, i have no idea of how to do this..

Comment: this is the closets i get , but i cant make it work with my code.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474883/rails-how-to-filter-results

Comment: Yes! im just looking at ransack already, anyway thanks for the answer just one thing... If i set a URL /candidates?position=position1  this will work right? .... i mean for the selectbox on the view

Comment: but the syntax is fine right domain.com/candidates?position=red

Comment: yes if form uses get request. you can use `index` action in controller.