# Rails - how to make query parameters optional in Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, optional-parameters

I am trying to build a filter area on my index with multiple parameters. My problem is that I don't know how to make each of them optional if I need to. I mean, even if I don't set a value to a field, I want my filter to only work with the ones I filled.

I wrote this code which works well, except when I remove one or several parameters.

```
def self.filter(type, min, max, start_at, end_at)
 where(type => min..max, :first_date => start_at..end_at).order("#{type}": :desc)
end
```

I know I can use `scope` but as I am new to Rails, it's pretty unclear. If somebody can come with some hints? Thanks!

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474883/rails-how-to-filter-results/15477926#15477926

Comment: @omnikron thanks for pointing me to this direction !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can atrriubte these to `nil`

```
def self.filter(type =nil, min=nil, max=nil, start_at=nil, end_at=nil)
  a = YourModel
  a = a.where(type => min..max) if min.present? && max.present?
  a = a.where(first_date: start_at..end_at) if start_at? && end_at.present?
  a = a.order("#{type}#": :desc) if type.present?
  a
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chain multiple where

```
result = where(type => min..max)
result = result.where(first_date: start_at..end_at) if start_date && end_date
return result
```