# ActiveRecord multiple where date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a more ActiveRecord idiomatic way to find which records have a `start_at` or `end_at` within a certain date_range? (Basically, need to find the records that start or end in a given time frame). Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
Project.where('(start_at >= ? AND start_at <= ?) OR (end_at >= ? AND end_at <= ?)', start_at, end_at, start_at, end_at)
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15477926/979091) using Arel's greater than/less than functions is helpful.

Comment: thanks omnikron ah, `gt` and `lt`, that's good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass [ranges](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#range-conditions) to `where` and use `or`:

```
time_range = (start_at..end_at)
Project.where(start_at: time_range).or(Project.where(end_at: time_range))
```

Comment: is `or` supported in Rails 4?

Comment: No, or comes in rails5

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for posting this.  Has just helped me immensely.

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 4 you could use `BETWEEN` and `hash` params:

```
Project.where(
  "(start_at BETWEEN :start_at AND :end_at) OR (end_at BETWEEN :start_at AND :end_at)",
  start_at: start_at.beginning_of_day, end_at: end_at.end_of_day)
```

Comment: is BETWEEN not inclusive? Is that why you are using `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day` ?

Comment: It depends of the datatype of your database column. `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day` ensure your query will return relevant results with a `DATETIME` type.